# How to generta MDX query from cube? How to call using olap4j?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap4j

Iam developing java spring batch. one task i need to call and execute SSAS cube process. How to generate MDX query from cube? and how to call mdx query using OLAP4j?

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far. Did anything work? Have you any example MDX from your cube, or example code?

Comment: Hi, I have used MS Job instance to execute/call cube process. In Job, I have created the Analysis command to execute. Now working. There are another way to execute MDX using OLAP4J jar. That too worked for me. By the way, No tutor/forums available to do with cube process from java.